# Set Buttons over ImageView - Android

Tags: android, button, imageview, drawable

I have a FlowLayout where a user can add tastes, like, music, games, sport, etc. After user informs what he wants to add, he clicks a button to display it in a flow layout, so, this process must be done programmatically. Create an image, set drawable and size. I did some of it. But now I need to display an imageview along with a button so a user can remove added taste. I think creating this process in xml will not help,  because user may not add any tastes.

What I've already done:

[image]

What I must do:

[image]

Method I'm using:

```
ImageView iconLike = new ImageView(Register30.this);
                    iconLike.setImageResource(getIconLike(like));
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(getSizeIconLike());
                    lp.setMargins(5,5,5,5);
                    iconLike.setLayoutParams(lp);
                    Like newLike = new Like();
                    newLike.setIcon(iconLike);
                    newLike.setGenderFather(null);
                    newLike.setGenderChild(null);
                    newLike.setName(like);
                    likes.add(newLike);
                    likesContainer.addView(iconLike);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to place buttons over Image in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14211484/how-to-place-buttons-over-image-in-android)

Comment: You should create them in XML and hide them and make them unclickable programmatically.

Comment: But the amount of tastes is unknown. User can add many or no one. Taste will exist when user search for it and then click a button to add it.

Comment: Use RecyclerView to create as many tastes as you want or none.

Answer (score 0):

Add in the xml 2 texts view with background of a circle

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


     <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/taste"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/remove"
        android:layout_width="width you want"
        android:layout_height="height you want"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:background="@drawable/circle_background_with 
        _your_color"
        android:visibility="gone"/>

     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/add"
        android:layout_width="width you want"
        android:layout_height="height you want"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@drawable/circle_background_with 
        _your_color"
        android:visibility="gone"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

when the user long clicks on a taste just change the visibility of the texts views. You need to set in the tastes adapter to every taste a longclick function. In this function you toggle between the states.

Comment: But the amount of tastes is unknown. User can add many or no one. Taste will exist when user search for it and then click a button to add it.